# Has anyone other than Sybill Trelawney made a real prediction/prophecy in HP world?

Tags: harry-potter, divination

We know that there are tons of prophecies held in the Ministry of Magic, but those are just records of past predictions, and we don't know who made them.

Aside from two prophecies made by Sybill Trelawney regarding Voldemort (to Dumbledore, and to Harry Potter), did the universe have an example of a specific person making a specific prophecy that was acknowledged to have been real prophecy and true?

The prophecy/prediction must be **specific** – I'm discounting dime-store-tarot-card-conman type predictions made by Trelawney in class, which amounted to either “broken clock” (someone will die this year) or “too vague to be false”. It must me non-obvious – e.g. you can't count the centaurs saying “There will be conflict because of Mars” (well duh, anyone could predict that based on geopolitics without the need for Mars-watching).

Comment: I assume all of the prophecies in the MoM are actual prophecies (even if they aren't necessarily _modern_ ones), but AFAIK they never specify any other specific prophet/prophetess

Comment: What about Harry and Ron correctly guessing (by accident) what would happen to Harry the following year. Would that count? :)

Comment: Two other, somewhat vague but accurate predictions: Neville breaking a teacup (dubious, given how clumsy he appears), and the death if Lavender Brown’s rabbit.

Comment: @alexwlchan - if you make a good case that they weren't typical ranom guesses or cons, you may have an answer.

Comment: I think you give the centaurs too little credit. First of all, why would they know anything about geopolitics when they shun human affairs? And why would it be obvious when everyone thought that Voldemort was done for and gone? It's kinda like predicting WWII during the unbridled optimism of the Roaring Twenties.

Comment: This question sure looks familiar :-P

Comment: Are you counting Sybill's great-great-grandmother who we are told by Dumbledore was a very gifted seer?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24567/4918 Was there any example of Centaurs legitimately divinating some true information?

Comment: Ron predicts in book 3, that Harry will win unexpected money. A year later Harry won the goblet of fire price.

Comment: @Lucharx - *did the universe have an example of a specific person making a specific prophecy that was acknowledged to have been **real prophecy** and true?*

Comment: There were some wild assumptions on Ron's guesses in the books. People say he was sort of correct in every suggestion he made and his words became true in the end. It was entertaining but nothing more I guess...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been several other named seers in Harry Potter dating back to Ancient Greece.

- **Mopsos** and **Calchas**

  > **Mopsus** (Ancient Greek, dates unknown)
  >   Ancient Greek soothsayer who vanquished the Seer Calchas in a contest of their powers.
  >   <sub>(Famous Wizard Cards)</sub>
- **Cassandra Vablatsky**

  > **Cassandra Vablatsky** (1894 - 1997)
  >   Celebrated Seer and author of Unfogging the Future.
  >   <sub>(Famous Wizard Cards)</sub>
- **Cassandra Trelawney**

  > “And you are a great-great-granddaughter of the celebrated Seer
  >   Cassandra Trelawney?”
  >   “Yes,” said Professor Trelawney, holding her head a little higher.
  >   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix -Chapter 15*)</sub>
- **Gellert Grindelwald**

  > **What did Graves-Grindelwald mean when he said: ”My vision showed only the child's immense power”? Is he a Seer or was he lying?**
  >   **J.K. Rowling**: *He is a Seer AND he was lying.*
  >   <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/810753569808875520)</sub>

While that concludes all of the named seers in Harry Potter, there are many others who have made real prophecies/predictions.

- Pottermore tells us about Naming Seers, which appears to have (at some point at least) been fairly widespread.

> A certain sector of magical society, however, follows the ancient wizarding practice of consulting a Naming Seer, who (usually for a hefty payment of gold) will predict the child's future and suggest an appropriate moniker.
>   <sub>([Pottermore - Naming Seers](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/naming-seers))</sub>

- All of the Prophecies in The Department of Mystery's 'Hall of Prophecies'.
  Of these, we only here snippets of two of them

  - > “. . . at the Solstice will come a new . . .” said the figure of an old,
    >   bearded man.
    >   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix -Chapter 35*)</sub>
  - > “. . . and none will come after . . .” said the figure of a young woman.
    >   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix -Chapter 35*)</sub>

### Bonus

> In the [original drafts for the books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KcvG.jpg), there was a blind character named Professor Mopsus who was skilled at Divination. Parts of him can be found in Trelawney, Mad-Eye Moody, and (Ancient Greek) Mopsus.
>
> > **Richard Wheatley for the RNIB:** - Blind children everywhere are delighted that they can read this book at the same time as sighted people, would you ever include a blind character in one of your Harry Potter books?
> >
> > **JK Rowling:** Funny you should say that because at one point there was a blind character who went by the name of Mopsus, and I will let you look him up because there is a mythological connection there, but he sort of ­­ that was a very early character and he had the power of second sight, in other words he was a bit like Professor Trelawney, he was a very, very early character, this was when I was drafting Philosopher's Stone, the reason I cut him was he was too good. As the story evolved, if there was somebody who really could do divination at the time that Harry was alive, it greatly diminished the drama of the story because someone out there knew what was going to happen.
> >     So that is why Mopsus went and I have never really replaced him, although I suppose Mad-Eye Moody, had some of Mopsus' characterisation. He has one magical eye because he lost an eye in a fight with a Death Eater, so good question.
> >     <sub>([Edinburgh "cub reporter" press conference, ITV, 16 July 2005](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-edinburgh-ITVcubreporters.htm))</sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: Didn't know about the naming seer, could that be an in-universe reason why Lupin is called Wolfy Wolf ? Must be a blow to the parents to learn that at birth..

Comment: As for named seers, Paracelsus was mentioned as a Chocolate Frog card in *Stone* ch. 6, and he was a diviner of legend in our world.  Iirc, Paracelsus is also mentioned once more to have a bust in Hogwarts in one of the books.

Comment: @b_jonas - There's like five different versions of the canon Paracelsus (depending on which video game platform you're playing on), but none of them mention him being a seer. As such, I'm going to assume that anything else about the historical character is as non-canon as that ridiculously long name that HP Wikia has decided he has.

Answer (score 6):

There is no mention in any of the books of any individuals possessing the seer gift other than Sybil Trelawney.  It is clear that this gift does actually exist, but there are no canon examples of other specific individuals who have made prophecies or the content of those prophecies, excepting only the prophecy fragments revealed when they start smashing orbs by destroying the shelves containing them.  None of the books Rowling has written to supplement the series(a set done to raise money for charity) mention prophecy, either.  There may be something buried in the bowels of her website, in a manner similar to how she revealed that Albus Dumbledore was gay, as I have not gone through that site.

Comment: There's Sybil's great-grandmother. But we never learn about any specific prophecies she made...

Answer (score 0):

Some of Professor Dumbledore's lucky guesses about the Dark Lord ought to count as a prophecy.

This one he tells to Professor Snape is particularly prescient: “There will come a time—after my death— […] There will come a time when Lord Voldemort will seem to fear for the life of his snake. […] If there comes a time when Lord Voldemort stops sending that snake forth to do his bidding, but keeps it safe beside him under magical protection, […]”

This prophecy comes true when the Dark Lord puts Nagini in a magical protective bubble.  Professor Dumbledore had to guess not only that Nagini is a Horcrux, but also that it is the Horcrux that would be destroyed the last, and how the Dark Lord will react to that.

Comment: This wasn't a prophecy, just the logical result of the final stages of his grand plan to defeat Voldemort.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there are no references said exactly to anyone else doing this except Lavender Brown's "Prophecy" and in the movie when the male, African american character(I think his name was Ben) interprets the Grimm tea leaves(that were Harry's), but there are characters that make prophecies(if you consider these prophecies).

- [Harry Potter wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Grim)

> The term 'Grim' was only first mentioned to Harry by Professor
> Trelawney during a Divination lesson studying the art of Tessomancy.
> When the tea leaves revealed the Grim, a horrified Professor Trelawney
> informed Harry, that the Grim is the possible omen of death. Harry's
> stomach "lurched" upon remembering he had witnessed the dog at
> Magnolia Crescent.

The grim was a "omen of death" and a:

> "The **giant, spectral dog** that haunts churchyards! My dear boy, it is
> an omen—the worst omen—of death!"
>
> —Sybill Trelawney discussing the Grim with Harry Potter

And the grim or Sirius Black did die or whoever the prophecy was talking about. Harry died, as well. And while Hermione is skeptical of it, she doesn't like things that are "wacky" and she has a dislike for Professor Trelawney.

- Taking [this site](http://www.hypable.com/2012/06/06/harry-potter-five-true-prophecies/) as a source they seem to have found many so-called prophecies.

Some of the notable ones:

The first to rise

> When 13 dine together, the first to rise will be the first to die.
> Indeed, although scoffed at by the vast majority eating that Christmas
> (PoA), this superstition is quite pertinent to the events of the Harry
> Potter series. Because, indeed, Harry/Ron wasn’t the first to rise –
> Dumbledore was; he rose to greet Trelawney. And Cedric definitely
> wasn’t there, as seen by the fact that J.K. Rowling quite clearly
> described which students were. This superstition appears to be quite
> consistent, as it was later used to forebode the deaths of both Sirius
> (at a meal in Grimauld Place) and Lupin (in Mad-Eye Moody’s ‘wake’).

Also, look at numbers 2 and 3. 3 mostly pertains directly to Divination. IIRC, they appeared to be nothing to the people that made them up, but they sometimes came true. Maybe I'm reading this wrong, or some people in the books/movie did make prophecies. You could say, though, that are mostly predictions. But [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prophecy) says that a prophecy is a:

> a. An inspired utterance of a prophet, viewed as a revelation of
> divine will.
>
> b. A **prediction** of the future, made under divine
> inspiration.
>
> c. Such an inspired message or prediction transmitted
> orally or in writing.

Comment: The question asked about "anyone other than Sybill Trelawney".

Comment: Having just rewatched that scene, the student you refer to is surely *not* "African-*American*"; his accent is plainly an English accent, he is pretty clearly not American. It's certainly possible his parents or grandparents (or more distant ancestors) might be African, but there's no way it makes any sense to refer to him as *American*. The terms used [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_England#Ethnicity) suggest "Black" or "Black British" might be accepted (which includes people whose ancestry is direct from Africa as well as those of Afro-Carribean descent, among others).

Comment: @Glen_b I meant he was of African descent. I sort of hurriedly wrote this. I will edit, but I think its kind of obvious that there are very few people that are obviously american in HP. :)

Answer (score -3):

According to me a gift(power) is given to grand grand mother of sybill to make real prophecies then obviously she had made prophecy(ies).

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say with this answer.  Are you saying that because Sybill Trelawney's grandmother had the "gift" like her, it is implied that she too had to have made prophecies?